# How to split the interval between two dates into details by month?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Sorry for the title ... it's best to describe the problem with an example ...

I have a list of events and two dates for each event and I need to "break" or "distribute" those dates within their respective months.

Example 1:

**Event**: Event A

**Start Date**: 12/15/2017 - MM/DD/YYYY

**End Date**: 01/17/2018 - MM/DD/YYYY

If I do a search on my table for this event, I get a result row with that data.

But I need two results, as shown below:

**Result 1: Event A > 15 to 31**

**Result 2: Event A > 01 to 17**

Example 2:

**Event**: Event B

**Start Date**: 02/07/2018 - MM/DD/YYYY

**End Date**: 04/22/2018 - MM/DD/YYYY

**Result 1: Event B > 07 to 28**

**Result 2: Event B > 01 to 31**

**Result 3: Event B > 01 to 22**

What is the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: I don't get where the 15 a 31 and 01 a 17 come from. Can you explain, or show several result examples so we can work that out with you?

Comment: The start date is on december of 2017, so 15 to 31 of december. And my end date is on january, so 01 to 17 of january.

Comment: So you would want to split a single record in multiple records whereas each record would never span multiple months? For example, if you had one event from Jan 1st to March 31st, you would one one record for Jan 1-31, one for Feb 1-28/29 and one for March 1-31?

Comment: Just saw your updated question, makes more sense now.

Comment: @SimonBerthiaume, exacltly

Comment: I liked your question and worked on it in Sql Server 2008. Now looking for better answers there. If anyone needs it for Sql Server, you may check:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49209755/how-to-display-a-record-multiple-times-including-day-intervals-based-on-its-star

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Oracle 12c `cross apply` clause can be used:

```
create table e_vents(
 name varchar2(10),
 startdate date,
 enddate date
);

insert all 
into e_vents values( 'A', date '2017-12-15', date '2018-01-17' )
into e_vents values( 'B', date '2017-12-15', date '2017-12-22' )
into e_vents values( 'C', date '2017-12-15', date '2018-05-22' )
select null from dual;

commit;
```

---

```
select e.name,
       case when e.startdate > x.s_date then e.startdate else x.s_date end as start_date,
       case when e.enddate < x.e_date then e.enddate else x.e_date end as end_date
from e_vents e
cross apply (
  select 
         trunc( e.startdate, 'mm') + (level-1) * interval '1' month as s_date,
         trunc( e.startdate + (level) * interval '1' month, 'mm') -1 as e_date 
  from dual
  connect by level <= months_between( trunc( e.enddate, 'mm'),trunc( e.startdate, 'mm')) + 1
) x
```

---

```
NAME       START_DATE END_DATE        
---------- ---------- ----------
A          2017-12-15 2017-12-31
A          2018-01-01 2018-01-17
B          2017-12-15 2017-12-22
C          2017-12-15 2017-12-31
C          2018-01-01 2018-01-31
C          2018-02-01 2018-02-28
C          2018-03-01 2018-03-31
C          2018-04-01 2018-04-30
C          2018-05-01 2018-05-22

9 rows selected.
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a full solution for you (if you create a workable [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4) testbench for it, I can probably work it out), but I think it's something requiring a CONNECT BY clause and it would be very close to [this solution from Ask Tom](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:4252846500346051124).

It goes basically something like this (example from Ask Tom):

```
variable sdate varchar2(30);
variable edate varchar2(30);
exec :sdate := '01-mar-2011'; :edate := '31-dec-2011';

select level r,
        greatest( add_months(trunc(sdate,'mm'),level-1), sdate ),
        least( last_day( add_months(sdate,level-1) ), edate )
from (select to_date( :sdate, 'dd-mon-yyyy' ) sdate,
                to_date( :edate, 'dd-mon-yyyy' ) edate
           from dual)
connect by level <= months_between( trunc( edate,'mm'), trunc(sdate,'mm') ) + 1;


     R GREATEST( LEAST(LAS
------ --------- ---------
     1 01-MAR-11 31-MAR-11
     2 01-APR-11 30-APR-11
     3 01-MAY-11 31-MAY-11
     4 01-JUN-11 30-JUN-11
     5 01-JUL-11 31-JUL-11
     6 01-AUG-11 31-AUG-11
     7 01-SEP-11 30-SEP-11
     8 01-OCT-11 31-OCT-11
     9 01-NOV-11 30-NOV-11
    10 01-DEC-11 31-DEC-11

10 rows selected.
```

Answer (score 1):

two solutions are available for this question

In Oracle 12C you can use the below query

```
SELECT DISTINCT e.name,
  CASE
    WHEN e.startdate > x.sdate
    THEN e.startdate
    ELSE x.sdate
  END AS startdate,
  CASE
    WHEN e.enddate < x.edate
    THEN e.enddate
    ELSE x.edate
  END AS enddate
FROM e_vents e CROSS apply
  (SELECT TRUNC( e.startdate, 'mm') + (level-1) * interval '1' MONTH         AS sdate,
    TRUNC( e.startdate              + (level) * interval '1' MONTH, 'mm') -1 AS edate
  FROM e_vents
    CONNECT BY level <= months_between( TRUNC( e.enddate, 'mm'),TRUNC( e.startdate, 'mm')) + 1
  ) x
ORDER BY 1 ASC;
```

in older versions of oracle use the below query

```
SELECT e.name,
  greatest(e.startdate,x.sdate) AS startdate,
  least(e.enddate,x.edate)      AS enddate
FROM e_vents e,
  (SELECT TRUNC( e.min_startdate, 'mm') + (level-1) * interval '1' MONTH         AS sdate,
    TRUNC( e.min_startdate              + (level) * interval '1' MONTH, 'mm') -1 AS edate
  FROM
    (SELECT MIN(startdate) min_startdate,MAX(enddate) max_enddate FROM e_vents
    ) e
    CONNECT BY level<= months_between( TRUNC( e.max_enddate, 'mm'),TRUNC( e.min_startdate, 'mm')) + 1
  ) x
WHERE e.startdate BETWEEN x.sdate AND x.edate
OR e.enddate BETWEEN x.sdate AND x.edate
OR x.sdate BETWEEN e.startdate AND e.enddate
OR x.edate BETWEEN e.startdate AND e.enddate
ORDER BY 1 ASC ;
```